# Drawing layout with constraints in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I wonder if it is implemented in `networkx.drawing` to hold one dimension during the layout optimization with a predefined position array.

Lets say you want to optimize the layout of a graph and have the x dimension of the positions already given, so you only want to optimize the y directions of the vertices.

So far I've only noticed, that one can hold positions of certain vertices, but then of course non of those are being moved.

In the Python package `grandalf`, they have DicgoLayout, so I'd expect something similar in `networkx`.

Comment: I guess it's difficult to understand clearly what you are saying.

Comment: thank you, tried to clarify it a bit more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with forking the spring layout with a *hold_dim* parameter, so during updating the positions only x or y is being changed.

Comment: Did you publish your modifications anywhere? This is exactly the solution to a problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: https://github.com/markovmodel/PyEMMA/blob/devel/pyemma/plots/_ext/fruchterman_reingold.py