# Constrained spring layout in networkx

Tags: networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed graph in networkx.

The nodes have a "height" label. Here is an example with heights 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6:

[image: Bruhat graph that I'm trying to Spring layout]

I would like to run spring layout (in two dimensions), but constrain the nodes to be of a fixed height. That is, I want to "constrain" spring layout so that the x coordinate of the nodes moves, by the y coordinate does not.

I am relatively new to networkx. What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Drawing layout with constraints in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987425/drawing-layout-with-constraints-in-networkx) with a link to a modification of the original algorithm [github link](https://github.com/markovmodel/PyEMMA/blob/devel/pyemma/plots/_ext/fruchterman_reingold.py) looks like an interesting approach.  (An alternative approach, working with JavaScript, might be the [d3 library](https://github.com/d3/d3-force)).

Comment: @JohanC: Fantastic. It look like that solves the problem. Thank you!

Comment: For what it is worth, a better layout optimisation criterion for directed, acyclic graphs such as yours is to minimize edge crossings. The most prominent algorithm to achieve that is the Sugiyama method. There are implementations in graphviz (`dot` layout) and grandalf. Networkx can wrap graphiz, my own library [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph) wraps grandalf.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen: thanks for this comment, I'll have a look at this too.

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson could you post your solution if possible?

Comment: @Joe: had a go, let me know how you go. I'm very new to this so there are probably much better ways. (Only doing this out of enormous gratitude for all the helpful things I've managed to find here in the past.)

Answer (score 1):

Following @Joe's request, I'm posting answer here.

This was just a matter of patching the code suggested above together. Thus absolutely no originality is claimed.

Your graph should have a "height" variable attached to each node. Thus, once you have added the code below, the following should work:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]])
for g in G.nodes():
  G.nodes()[g]["height"] = g
draw_graph_with_height(G,figsize=(5,5))
```

[image]

```
#    Copyright (C) 2004-2015 by
#    Aric Hagberg <hagberg@lanl.gov>
#    Dan Schult <dschult@colgate.edu>
#    Pieter Swart <swart@lanl.gov>
#    All rights reserved.
#    BSD license.
# import numpy as np

# taken from networkx.drawing.layout and added hold_dim
def _fruchterman_reingold(A, dim=2, k=None, pos=None, fixed=None,
                          iterations=50, hold_dim=None):
    # Position nodes in adjacency matrix A using Fruchterman-Reingold
    # Entry point for NetworkX graph is fruchterman_reingold_layout()
    try:
        nnodes, _ = A.shape
    except AttributeError:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "fruchterman_reingold() takes an adjacency matrix as input")

    A = np.asarray(A)  # make sure we have an array instead of a matrix

    if pos is None:
        # random initial positions
        pos = np.asarray(np.random.random((nnodes, dim)), dtype=A.dtype)
    else:
        # make sure positions are of same type as matrix
        pos = pos.astype(A.dtype)

    # optimal distance between nodes
    if k is None:
        k = np.sqrt(1.0 / nnodes)
    # the initial "temperature"  is about .1 of domain area (=1x1)
    # this is the largest step allowed in the dynamics.
    t = 0.1
    # simple cooling scheme.
    # linearly step down by dt on each iteration so last iteration is size dt.
    dt = t / float(iterations + 1)
    delta = np.zeros((pos.shape[0], pos.shape[0], pos.shape[1]), dtype=A.dtype)
    # the inscrutable (but fast) version
    # this is still O(V^2)
    # could use multilevel methods to speed this up significantly
    for _ in range(iterations):
        # matrix of difference between points
        for i in range(pos.shape[1]):
            delta[:, :, i] = pos[:, i, None] - pos[:, i]
        # distance between points
        distance = np.sqrt((delta**2).sum(axis=-1))
        # enforce minimum distance of 0.01
        distance = np.where(distance < 0.01, 0.01, distance)
        # displacement "force"
        displacement = np.transpose(np.transpose(delta)*(k * k / distance**2 - A * distance / k))\
            .sum(axis=1)
        # update positions
        length = np.sqrt((displacement**2).sum(axis=1))
        length = np.where(length < 0.01, 0.1, length)
        delta_pos = np.transpose(np.transpose(displacement) * t / length)
        if fixed is not None:
            # don't change positions of fixed nodes
            delta_pos[fixed] = 0.0
        # only update y component
        if hold_dim == 0:
            pos[:, 1] += delta_pos[:, 1]
        # only update x component
        elif hold_dim == 1:
            pos[:, 0] += delta_pos[:, 0]
        else:
            pos += delta_pos
        # cool temperature
        t -= dt
        pos = _rescale_layout(pos)
    return pos

def _rescale_layout(pos, scale=1):
    # rescale to (0,pscale) in all axes

    # shift origin to (0,0)
    lim = 0  # max coordinate for all axes
    for i in range(pos.shape[1]):
        pos[:, i] -= pos[:, i].min()
        lim = max(pos[:, i].max(), lim)
    # rescale to (0,scale) in all directions, preserves aspect
    for i in range(pos.shape[1]):
        pos[:, i] *= scale / lim
    return pos

def draw_graph_with_height(g,highlighted_nodes=set([]),figsize=(15,15),iterations=150,title=''):
  """ Try to draw a reasonable picture of a graph with a height feature on each node."""

  pos = { p : (5*np.random.random(),2*data["height"]) for (p,data) in g.nodes(data=True)} # random x, height fixed y.

  pos_indices = [i for i in pos.keys()]
  pos_flat = np.asarray([pos[i] for i in pos.keys()])
  A = nx.adjacency_matrix(g.to_undirected())
  Adense = A.todense()
  Adensefloat = Adense.astype(float)
  new_pos = _fruchterman_reingold(Adensefloat, dim=2, pos=pos_flat, fixed=[0,len(pos_flat)-1], iterations=iterations, hold_dim=1)

  pos_dict = { pos_indices[i] : tuple(new_pos[i]) for i in range(len(pos_indices))}

# for u,v,d in g.edges(data=True):
#   d['weight'] = float(d['t'][1]-d['t'][0])

# edges,weights = zip(*nx.get_edge_attributes(g,'weight').items())
# print(weights)

  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)

  if title: fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=16)

  if highlighted_nodes:
    nx.draw(g, pos=pos_dict, alpha=.1, font_size=14,node_color='b')
    gsub = nx.subgraph(g,highlighted_nodes)
    nx.draw(gsub, pos=pos_dict, node_color='r')

  else:
    nx.draw(g,pos=pos_dict)

  plt.show()
```